# Symfony Assetic wrong resource type

Tags: html, css, apache, symfony

I have a strange problem with symfony 2. I'm working on a project that has all the stylesheets and javascript files loaded with asset(path/to/file) and i decided to use assetic with cssrewrite and yui_compressor so i added them like this:

```
// this is just one file for example
{% stylesheets
    'bundles/mybundle/css/main.css'
    filter='?cssrewrite, ?yui_css'
%}
```

Now eveything works perfect in prod env but the problem is in the dev environment. The file is linked correct, i can open the file but resource type is actually text/html instead of text/css even though the type is set to text/css like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app_dev.php/css/ab72c13_main_1.css"/>
```

What could cause this strange problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "resource type is actually text/html instead of text/css". From where do you get this information? Also, note that using `?` in front of your filter tells Assetic NOT to process them so this is unlikely to be an Assetic problem (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/yuicompressor.html#disable-minification-in-debug-mode).

Comment: i know but before i used assetic this problem didn't exist so i presumed it was assetic. i noticed that the css file is not applied at all so i checked in chrome's debug toolbar ( or whatever is called) and there i saw that the resource is of type text/html

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Can you show us the full `{% stylesheets %}` from your twig template?

Comment: it's just this and another file because i wanted to add them one by one ... both files act the same

Comment: What if you let the `cssrewrite` filter even in dev by removing the `?` in front of it?

Comment: @cheesemacfly nope :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the problem, with the help of @cordoval.

I had two files that configured assetic: use_controller and one of the was overriding the other one with true.

So the solution to this problem is to set assetic: use_controller : false and use assetic:dump --watch to automatically dump the assetic in case you don't want to do that every time you modify a css/js file.

Comment: I have use_controller : false and it still fetches the wrong mimetype.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the yui_css filter and testing the other in isolation.

Comment: i tried and after doing cache:clear and assetic:dump it's the same thing

Comment: Sorry, you only have them enabled in prod anyway so that' wouldn't matter.  assetic:dump isn't required either as you are serving through the controller in dev.

Comment: i'm not using the controller

Comment: The <link you pasted has the href that points to the front controller, and the CSS is loaded through that. What is your actual <link in your twig template? href="{{ asset_url }}"?

Comment: yes

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>`

Comment: So yes you are going through the front controller. And you have installed assets using assets:install? That places them where you need to target them how you are using bundles/mybundle format. Have you tried loading using the @notation?

Comment: Yes i tried with @ too. regarding the controller i was thinking at use_controller that i have it set to false in assetic configuration

Answer (score 0):

Check your `security.yml` and be sure that the css files are acessible to **all** roles

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```